# Typescript: Calling overload with multiple types

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a class method, which accepts three different types of values: `string`, `Buffer` and `Uint8Array`.

I want to convert the type to Buffer if it's not a Buffer, so I check if it's **not** a Buffer using `!Buffer.isBuffer(...)`, then attempt to convert it to a Buffer using `Buffer.from(...)`, which should accept either of the remaining types (`string` | `UInt8Array`).

Unfortunately Typescript thinks I'm trying to convert a `UInt8Array` into a `string`, which I'm clearly not, so I have to add a manual `typeof` check to keep it happy.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
public send(data: string | Buffer | Uint8Array): void {
  if (!Buffer.isBuffer(data)) {
    if (typeof data === 'string') {
      data = Buffer.from(data); // string
    } else {
      data = Buffer.from(data); // Uint8Array
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add "node" to the tags for this, or something?  I don't have `Buffer` in scope anywhere.  Ideally example code would constitute a [mcve] so that people can just drop it into an IDE to reproduce your issue and only your issue.  It seems to depend heavily on `Buffer`, so either you only want people who have node in their environment or you should provide a link to a web IDE that has such dependencies already configured.  Hope you get an answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Sorry about that! I hadn't really considered people trying to reproduce the issue, but merely was trying to explain the difficulty I was having in Typescript. I have added the node.js tag, Thanks!

Comment: It's okay! A standalone reproducible example (among other things in the guidelines about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) increase a question's chances of getting a good, relevant answer. The best way to explain the difficulty you are facing is to enable others to see it firsthand. Otherwise all you'll get are maybe-good but untested guesses, such as: if the issue is that `Buffer.from()` is overloaded in a way that prevents your intended use, you could [merge in](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) your own signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little thinking about it, I think the issue is because of the way the overloads are written in the [`Buffer.from(...) type annotations on the DefinatelyTyped repository`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5344bfc80508c53a23dae37b860fb0c905ff7b24/types/buffer-from/index.d.ts)

```
declare function bufferFrom(arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer, byteOffset?: number, length?: number): Buffer;
declare function bufferFrom(str: string, encoding?: string): Buffer;
declare function bufferFrom(data: ReadonlyArray<any> | Buffer): Buffer;
```

From within Javascript, it would handle `ArrayBuffer | string | ReadOnlyArray<any>` (actually `any`), but due to Typescript's method overloading, it expects only one of these types.

If anyone has a better answer, I'd be happy to hear it.